# Show $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{r^i}{k-i}$ for $r \in (0,1)$ goes to 0 as $k\to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wish to show that the following sequence $\alpha_k$ which is an infinite summation goes to 0 as $k\to\infty$

Let $$\alpha_k = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{r^i}{k-i}\quad r \in (0,1)$$
Then show that the sequence $\{\alpha_k\}$ converges to 0

Each term is clearly 0 as $k\to \infty$, but i'm unable to upperbound the infinite sum.

Comment: That sum doesn't make sense. What happens when $i=k$?

Comment: My apologies. That should read sum to $k-1$. Correcting now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$0 \leq \alpha_k \leq \sum\limits_{i=0}^{m} \frac {r^{i}} {k-i}+\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{k-1} \frac {r^{i}} {k-i}$ for any $m<k$. The second term is bounded by $\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{k-1}  {r^{i}} $. It is easy to see that $\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{\infty}  {r^{i}}  \to 0$ as $m \to \infty$ (by writing down the geometric sum explcitly). So choose and fix $m$ so that the second term is less than $\epsilon$. Now let $k \to \infty $ in the first term (with $m$ fixed).